# Exporting Selection to CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I've created a excel spreadsheet template for our customers to populate and send back to us.  I want to manually select their populated data and save it as a .csv to import into another piece of software.  I, first, attempted this by recording a macro.  This didn't work because different customers send different numbers of records.

I've tried snippets of code from online research and came up with this.

```
Sub Select_To_CSV()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim myrangearea()
   Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select


   Dim myPath As String, v
   myPath = "p:\" & _
     Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
   'myPath = "x:\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
    v = SaveAs(myPath)
    If v <> False Then ThisWorkbook.SaveAs v
End Sub

Function SaveAs(initialFilename As String)
  On Error GoTo EndNow
  SaveAs = False
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "&Save As"
    .initialFilename = initialFilename
    .Title = "File Save As"
    '.Execute
    .Show
    SaveAs = .SelectedItems(1)
  End With
EndNow:
End Function

Sub Select_To_CSV()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim myrangearea()
   Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select


   Dim myPath As String, v
   myPath = "p:\" & _
     Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
   'myPath = "x:\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
    v = SaveAs(myPath)
    If v <> False Then ThisWorkbook.SaveAs v
End Sub
```

This worked really well except when I went back to look at the .csv in the folder it was the same worksheet not the selected columns.

Ultimately what I am looking to do is,

1. Manually select the columns I want
2. Run a macro that converts the selected columns to a .csv
3. Have the Save As Dialog Box appear
4. Navigate to the certain folder I want.

Comment: I believe only the sheet can be saved as CSV, not part of it, you may have to transfer the used data to an empty sheet and then save as csv.

Comment: You code won't compile. It looks like you've messed up your code paste. Please edit your question and paste working code. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've a couple of good starts that just didn't get completed. How were you planning to select the columns before launching the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Sub MacroMan()

ChDrive "P:" '// <~~ change current drive to P:\
Dim copyRng As Excel.Range
Dim ThisWB  As Excel.Workbook
Dim OtherWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim sName   As String

'// set reference to the 'Master' workbook
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook

'// assign selected range to 'copyRng'
Set copyRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range to convert to CSV", Type:=8)

'// If the user selected a range, then proceed with rest of code:
If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
    '// Create a new workbook with 1 sheet.
    Set OtherWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

    '// Get A1, then expand this 'selection' to the same size as copyRng. 
    '// Then assign the value of copyRng to this area (similar to copy/paste)
    OtherWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(copyRng.Rows.Count, copyRng.Columns.Count).Value = copyRng.Value

    '// Get save name for CSV file.
    sName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="CSV files (*.csv), *.csv")

    '// If the user entered a save name then proceed:
    If Not LCase(sName) = "false" Then
        '// Turn off alerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '// Save the 'copy' workbook as a CSV file
        OtherWB.SaveAs sName, xlCSV
        '// Close the 'copy' workbook
        OtherWB.Close
        '// Turn alerts back on
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    '// Make the 'Master' workbook the active workbook again
    ThisWB.Activate

    MsgBox "Conversion complete", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

This will allow you to manually select a range (including entire columns). It will then transfer said range onto a new sheet, save that sheet as a CSV, using the Save As dialog, and then close it afterwards.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I have two more questions.  Is there any way you could comment out the code so I could learn exactly what the code is doing?  Also, how would i send the file to the same folder everytime?  Thanks again for your help.  Really awesome to see it done correctly.

Comment: 1) see edit above. 2) Not sure what you mean, are you going to run this code multiple times in succession and don't want to select a folder each time?

Comment: Thanks for the code comments.  I understand it better.  What I mean is that I am going to save the csv to my p:\ drive everytime.  When the save as opens I would like for it to go straight to my p:\ drive and then I navigate from there.  Does that make sense?  Thanks again for the help

Comment: Thanks again.  Works awesome!!